# GAE app logs tail to include app's log , not just http request log

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-stackdriver

After deploying an app (made of spring boot and kotlin) to Google App Engine , I can use
`$ gcloud app logs tail`  to monitor the latest logs :

[image: tail logs]

But it doesn't show logs output by applications.
I have to use browser to go to `StackDriver` to browse online logs .
This is not convenient.

Another way is to use command line to read `request_log` by `gcloud logging` command :

`gcloud logging read request_log --limit=10`

But it doesn't support `tail` mode , and it outputs too much payload data (such as labels , requestId , zone ... blah...). I tried many formats but still output too much payloads.

I just want to see what's output by `logger.info("...")` or higher level

Is there any way for `gcloud app logs tail` also output logs by apps ? Or any other way to **tail** (monitor) app's log in the console ?

The logging code is simple (by slf4j) :

```
@RestController
class WebhookController {

  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)!!

  @GetMapping("/")
  fun index(req: HttpServletRequest): String {
    logger.info("header : ")
    for (headerName in req.headerNames) {
      logger.info("\t{} = {}", headerName, req.getHeader(headerName))
    }
    logger.info("params : ")
    req.parameterMap.forEach { (k, v) ->
      logger.info("\t{} = {}", k, v)
    }
    return "Hello Spring Boot Kotlin "
  }
}
```

Environment :

`logging.properties`

```
.level = INFO
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
```

`appengine-web.xml`

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

and

```
Google Cloud SDK 220.0.0
app-engine-java 1.9.66
<kotlin.version>1.2.71</kotlin.version>
<springboot.version>2.0.5.RELEASE</springboot.version>
<spring.version>5.0.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

updated : StackDriver in browser sample :
[image]
I am only interested in the red-circled part. But not output in `gcloud app logs tail`

Answer (score 0):

Your application logs should be going into the `stdout` stream, which you can select using the `--logs` option of the `gcloud app logs tail` command.

```
gcloud app logs tail --logs=stdout
```

See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/tail

Comment: Sorry , it doesn't work. In fact , the default `--logs` contains `stderr,stdout,crash.log,nginx.request,request_log` .

Comment: Yes , I mentioned `I have to use browser to go to StackDriver to browse online logs . This is not convenient.` It has a lot of payloads.

Comment: So, in the browser, under which log stream do the logs appear? Is it `stdout`? In that case you're saying there is a bug in gcloud. Correct?

Comment: I've appended a StackDriver snapshot , FYI. There is `<stdout>` , but not output by `gcloud app logs tail`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky but what you can do is:

1. Use `watch -n 1` to run the command every second (tail-like workaround)
2. Use `gcloud logging read "request_log" --limit=10 --format=json` to format it as json so that you can then parse it with jq
3. Pipe the output to jq so that it prints only the log message instead of all the other payload data, for example `jq ".[].protoPayload.line | .[] | .logMessage"`

So the full command would be:

```
watch -n 1 'gcloud logging read "request_log" --limit=10 --format=json | jq ".[].protoPayload.line | .[] | .logMessage"'
```

So if the log entry is like this:

```
[
  {
    "httpRequest": {
      "status": 200
    },
    ...,
    "protoPayload": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog",
      ...
      "line": [
        {
          "logMessage": "This is an info message",
          "severity": "INFO",
          ...

        }
      ]
    }
    ...
  }
]
```

Then with `jq ".[].protoPayload.line | .[] | .logMessage"` you'll be getting only this:

```
"This is an info message"
```

You can also add `.time` so that you get the timestamp of the log message:

`jq ".[].protoPayload.line | .[] | .logMessage ,.time"`

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to the **beta** version of the tool!

With something like `gcloud beta app logs tail --project=... --logs=stdout,stderr`, I get the expected traces from my live code.

Answer (score -1):

I am using laravel and had same problem. Finally, I add in my `app.yaml` 
add

```
env_variables:
    ...
    LOG_CHANNEL: stderr
```

And thats helps me tailing app Logs like that:

```
Log::info( $data );
```

And as a recommendation, $data shoud be like JSON - for easy reading throu console.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding a piece of code as an answer, doesn't per say help OP or future community members understand the issue or the proposed solution.